# rails db schema sql format TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

After I added this line to my application.rb file

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

I start getting this error when I am running migration

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace



** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:structure:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:structure:dump
I, [2016-06-21T08:09:14.083751 #51538]  INFO -- : [Rollbar] Scheduling item
I, [2016-06-21T08:09:14.102300 #51538]  INFO -- : [Rollbar] Details: https://rollbar.com/instance/uuid?uuid=fgfffgf (only available if report was successful)
rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:99:in `system'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:99:in `run_cmd'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:64:in `structure_dump'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:207:in `structure_dump'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:292:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:67:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:59:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:24:in `run'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:304:in `exec'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:19:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:dump
```

This error is disapiars if I remove that line from application.rb

Also one of my tables uses JSONB data field, not sure if this problem releated to this.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this problem when I was using environment variables for all the settings in config/database.yml but didn't have the database name environment variable defined.